# How to typecast SIMD3<Float> ARFaceGeometry Vertice coordinates

Tags: swift, type-conversion, arkit

Could anyone please advice what the easiest way in Swift would be to convert the face vertex coordinates given by:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arfacegeometry/2928201-vertices

to any nice float array/matrix?
The debugger gives the values of one of these elements to be:

```
SIMD3<Float>(-0.0314863473, -0.0266291834, 0.045474831)
```

but I would just like to typecase in a way so I could extract the raw data.

Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

You can access the three values of `SIMD3<Float>` using `x`, `y`, and `z` accessors. There is no need to convert to another type.